# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, html5-canvas

I am working on a real time white board sharing project.
In here the presenter is the one who can draw and the other people who joined the room are shown the real time image instead of canvas. Inorder to show the real time image. I added conditional rendering

```jsx
{!user?.presenter ? <CanvasViewer img={img} /> : <canvas ref={canvasRef} />}
```

error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')
    at new B (rough.esm.js:1:1)
    at Object.canvas (rough.esm.js:1:1)
    at Canvas.jsx:51:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'strokeStyle')
    at Canvas.jsx:40:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Canvas> component:

    at Canvas (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:258:5)
    at div
    at div
```

Here is the component code:

```jsx
import { useEffect, useState, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import rough from "roughjs/bundled/rough.esm.js";
import CanvasViewer from "../CanvasViewer/CanvasViewer";

const roughGenerator = rough.generator();

const Canvas = ({
  canvasRef,
  ctxRef,
  elements,
  setElements,
  tool,
  color,
  user,
  socket,
}) => {
  const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false);
  const [img, setImg] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    if (canvas) {
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 2;
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 2;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.lineCap = "round";

      ctxRef.current = ctx;
    }
  }, [canvasRef, color]);

  useEffect(() => {
    ctxRef.current.strokeStyle = color;
  }, [color]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("whiteBoardDataResponse", (data) => {
      setImg(data.imgURL);
    });
  }, []);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (canvasRef) {
      const roughCanvas = rough.canvas(canvasRef.current);

      if (elements.length > 0) {
        ctxRef.current.clearRect(
          0,
          0,
          canvasRef.current.width,
          canvasRef.current.height,
        );
      }

      elements.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.type === "rect") {
          roughCanvas.draw(
            roughGenerator.rectangle(
              element.offsetX,
              element.offsetY,
              element.width,
              element.height,
              {
                stroke: element.stroke,
                strokeWidth: 5,
                roughness: 0,
              },
            ),
          );
        } else if (element.type === "line") {
          roughCanvas.draw(
            roughGenerator.line(
              element.offsetX,
              element.offsetY,
              element.width,
              element.height,
              {
                stroke: element.stroke,
                strokeWidth: 5,
                roughness: 0,
              },
            ),
          );
        } else if (element.type === "pencil") {
          roughCanvas.linearPath(element.path, {
            stroke: element.stroke,
            strokeWidth: 5,
            roughness: 0,
          });
        }
      });

      const canvasImage = canvasRef.current.toDataURL();
      socket.emit("whiteboardData", canvasImage);
    }
  }, [elements]);

  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = e.nativeEvent;

    if (tool === "pencil") {
      setElements((prevElements) => [
        ...prevElements,
        {
          type: "pencil",
          offsetX,
          offsetY,
          path: [[offsetX, offsetY]],
          stroke: color,
        },
      ]);
    } else if (tool === "line") {
      setElements((prevElements) => [
        ...prevElements,
        {
          type: "line",
          offsetX,
          offsetY,
          width: offsetX,
          height: offsetY,
          stroke: color,
        },
      ]);
    } else if (tool === "rect") {
      setElements((prevElements) => [
        ...prevElements,
        {
          type: "rect",
          offsetX,
          offsetY,
          width: 0,
          height: 0,
          stroke: color,
        },
      ]);
    }

    setIsDrawing(true);
  };

  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = e.nativeEvent;

    if (isDrawing) {
      if (tool === "pencil") {
        const { path } = elements[elements.length - 1];
        const newPath = [...path, [offsetX, offsetY]];
        setElements((prevElements) =>
          prevElements.map((ele, index) => {
            if (index === elements.length - 1) {
              return {
                ...ele,
                path: newPath,
              };
            } else {
              return ele;
            }
          }),
        );
      } else if (tool === "line") {
        setElements((prevElements) =>
          prevElements.map((ele, index) => {
            if (index === elements.length - 1) {
              return {
                ...ele,
                width: offsetX,
                height: offsetY,
              };
            } else {
              return ele;
            }
          }),
        );
      } else if (tool === "rect") {
        setElements((prevElements) =>
          prevElements.map((ele, index) => {
            if (index === elements.length - 1) {
              return {
                ...ele,
                width: offsetX - ele.offsetX,
                height: offsetY - ele.offsetY,
              };
            } else {
              return ele;
            }
          }),
        );
      }
    }
  };

  const handleMouseUp = (e) => {
    setIsDrawing(false);
  };

  return (
    <div
      onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
      onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
      className="border border-dark border-3 h-100 w-100 overflow-hidden"
    >
      {!user?.presenter ? (
        <CanvasViewer img={img} />
      ) : (
        <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Canvas;
```

This is the component that is calling Canvas Component:

```jsx
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./RoomPage.css";
import Canvas from "../../Components/Canvas/Canvas";

function RoomPage({ user, socket }) {
  const canvas = useRef(null);
  const ctx = useRef(null);
  const [tool, setTool] = useState("pencil");
  const [color, setColor] = useState("black");
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([]);

  const handleCanvasClear = () => {
    const canvasRef = canvas.current;
    if (canvasRef) {
      const ctxRef = canvasRef.getContext("2d");
      ctxRef.fillRect = "white";
      ctxRef.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.current.width, canvas.current.height);
      setElements([]);
    }
  };

  const undoHandler = () => {
    //add last element to history
    setHistory((prev) => [...prev, elements[elements.length - 1]]);

    //remove last element from elements
    setElements((prev) => prev.slice(0, prev.length - 1));
  };

  const redoHandler = () => {
    setElements((prev) => [...prev, history[history.length - 1]]);

    setHistory((prev) => prev.slice(0, prev.length - 1));
  };

  return (
    <div className="room">
      <h1 className="text-center py-4">
        WHITE BOARD SHARING{" "}
        <span className="text-primary">[Users Online: 0]</span>
      </h1>

      {user && user.presenter && (
        <div className="col-md-10 mx-auto px-5 mt-3 mb-5 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div className="d-flex col-md-2 justify-content-center gap-1">
            <div className="d-flex gap-1 align-items-center">
              <label htmlFor="pencil">Pencil</label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                className="mt-1"
                checked={tool === "pencil"}
                name="tool"
                id="pencil"
                value="pencil"
                onChange={(e) => setTool(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="d-flex gap-1 align-items-center">
              <label htmlFor="line">Line</label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                className="mt-1"
                checked={tool === "line"}
                name="tool"
                id="line"
                value="line"
                onChange={(e) => setTool(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="d-flex gap-1 align-items-center">
              <label htmlFor="rect">Rectangle</label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                className="mt-1"
                checked={tool === "rect"}
                name="tool"
                id="rect"
                value="rect"
                onChange={(e) => setTool(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-3 mx-auto">
            <div className="d-flex  align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <label htmlFor="color">Select Color:</label>
              <input
                type="color"
                id="color"
                className="mt-1 ms-3"
                value={color}
                onChange={(e) => setColor(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-3 d-flex gap-2">
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary mt-1"
              disabled={elements.length === 0}
              onClick={() => undoHandler()}
            >
              Undo
            </button>
            <button
              className="btn btn-outline-primary mt-1"
              disabled={history.length === 0}
              onClick={() => redoHandler()}
            >
              Redo
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-3">
            <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={handleCanvasClear}>
              Clear
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}

      <div className="col-md-10 border canvas-box">
        <Canvas
          canvasRef={canvas}
          ctxRef={ctx}
          elements={elements}
          setElements={setElements}
          tool={tool}
          color={color}
          user={user}
          socket={socket}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RoomPage;
```

The props I have sent to canvas are from RoomPage. getContext is all being used in RoomPage. But I think the problem is with in Canvas.

Comment: Can you create a running demo using https://codesandbox.io/dashboard?

Comment: Wait, why are you accepting `canvasRef` as a prop to your `Canvas` component? That doesn't make sense and typically, React won't let you do that without [forwardRef](https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef)

Comment: Yeah, not sure what I was thinking of, but you're right.

Comment: I have updated the above code with the required details you can take a look at it.

Comment: Canvas is a component and canvas is the html element.

Comment: Looks like a **TYPO**. The error is here in your `useLayoutEffect` hook... `if (canvasRef) { const roughCanvas = rough.canvas(canvasRef.current)`. You're checking `canvasRef` but not `canvasRef.current` so on initial render, you're passing `null` to `rough.canvas()`

Comment: canvasRef.current did work but the error: cannot set properties of null(setting: 'strokestyle') still persists

Comment: `canvasRef.current` did work but the error: `Canvas.jsx:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'strokeStyle')
    at Canvas.jsx:42:1` still persists

Answer (score 0):

Following are the changes made:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    if (canvas.current) {
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 2;
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 2;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      if(ctx){
      ctx.strokeStyle = color;
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.lineCap = "round";

      ctxRef.current = ctx;
     }
    }
  }, [canvasRef, color]);
```

needed to add conditional check of canvas and ctxRef in all the useEffects.